# checkbox control of input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two checkboxes and two input fields. Only one checkbox can be active (checked) at the time. If second is activated, first one is unchecked.. etc.

Now inputs. I am using css to set input field to readonly and color it when checkbox is unchecked. If checkbox is checked, its input field is set to rw and color is unset. At this point other checkbox should be deactivated and its input field set to readonly + specific color.

This is my code. Separately code works, but when both functions are put together, it does not behave properly. Other checkbox is unchecked but input field is not set as readonly+color.

```js
//css control  
function f_ro_rw(check, elm, para, init) {
          if (init == 1)
            document.getElementById(elm).onchange()
          if (document.getElementById(check).checked) {
            document.getElementById(elm).className = document.getElementById(elm).className.replace(/^ro[ w30]*/,"rw "+para)
            document.getElementById(elm).readOnly=false
          }
          else {
            document.getElementById(elm).className = document.getElementById(elm).className.replace(/^rw[ w30]*/,"ro "+para)
            document.getElementById(elm).readOnly=true
          }
        }

//checkbox control 
    function httpChange(obj) {
      var ht = document.getElementsByClassName("ht");
      for (var i = 0; i < ht.length; i++) {
          ht[i].checked = false;
      }
      obj.checked = true;
    }
```

```css
input.ro {background: #4d4d4d; color: #fff}
input.w30 {width: 120px}
```

```html
<input id="httprecstringAV" name="httprecstringAV" type="checkbox" class="ht" onchange="httpChange(this); f_ro_rw(this.id, 'customrecstring', ' w30')" />
<input id="customrecstring" name="customrecstring" type="text" value="AVAILABLE" class="ro w30" readonly="readonly"/>

<input id="httprecstring301" name="httprecstring301" type="checkbox" class="ht" onchange="httpChange(this); f_ro_rw(this.id, 'customrecstring301', ' w30')" />
<input id="customrecstring301" name="customrecstring301" type="text" value="301" class="ro w30" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: *Only one checkbox can be active (checked) at the time.* <-- Then you should be using radio buttons.

Comment: *I am using css to set input field to readonly* <-- That's not possible.

Comment: radio buttons looks ugly and "Im using javascript to change css" - to answer Marcus :) -sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using checkboxes is an immediate user experience red flag. People expect that with checkboxes you can select some, none or all of them and people expect that with radio buttons you have a mutually exclusive set. Just because you think radio buttons are ugly, is not really a valid reason to defy everyone's expectations of how a web page operates.

Additionally, radio buttons already implement that mutual exclusivity so you don't have to reinvent it.

All that you'd need to do with radio buttons is set up a single CSS class that styles the `checked` one and your done.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

// find all the relevant elements and loop over the collection of them
buttons.forEach(function(el){
  // Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not in HTML
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Loop over the radio buttons again
    buttons.forEach(function(rad){
      // make the textbox after each read only 
      rad.nextElementSibling.readOnly = true;
    });
    // now make the clicked one not read only
    el.nextElementSibling.readOnly = false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* default style for textboxes */
input[type='radio'] + input{
  background-color:grey;
}

/** checked style for textboxes */
input[type='radio']:checked + input{
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="http"><input readonly value="something"> 
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="cust"><input readonly value="something else">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Issue is, when I have 6 options to check, and these options are mutually exclusive with others in some specific fashion, lets say first one cannot be checked if 6th is checked, second if 3rd or 4th is checked. This was the reason I wanted checkbox instead radio button. My example what I wanted to accomplish had just two options, for simplicity, so I could learn what is going wrong and how to go from there and learn. For what I want to accomplish in larger scale, radios will not work. I guess I should be more specific with my question.
Anyway, thanks again for your input.